# "J'ai tout oublié" ou "J'ai oublié tout"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

Dit-on

> J'ai tout oublié.

or

> J'ai oublié tout.

pour

> I have forgotten everything.

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La bonne expression est  :

> J'ai tout oublié.

On peut dire « J'ai oublié tout » si on y ajoute un complément, comme :

> J'ai oublié tout *ce que tu m'as fait*.

ou

> J'ai oublié tout *ce que j'ai appris jusqu'ici*.

Comment: Peut-on dire "J'ai tout oublié ce que tu m'as fait" ?

Comment: @user11550: Il faudrait alors dire : « J'ai tout oublié **de** ce que tu m'as fait. »

Comment: Merci. Et peut-on dire "J'ai oublié tout **de** ce que tu m'as fait" ?

Comment: @user11550: Réponse courte : « non »